# How to user monit to count the number of instances of a process

Tags: monit, system-monitoring

Is it possible to use [`monit`](http://mmonit.com/monit/) to count the number of instances of a process (in my case [`Celery`](http://www.celeryproject.org/)) and take an action accordingly.

For example if there are 4 instances of celery daemon, then take action

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should be doable using a short shell script, and program status testing. Something like

```
check program countCelery with path /usr/local/bin/countCelery.sh with timeout 600 seconds:
if status != 0 alert
```

with a shell script like:

```
#!/bin/bash
celery_count=$(pgrep -c Celery)
if [[ $celery_count -gt 4 ]]; then
  exit 1
else:
  exit 0
fi
```

Comment: cool. i will test this right away and let u know

Comment: In the version of Monit we use, the syntax is -- 
check program countCelery with path /usr/local/bin/countCelery.sh
 with timeout 30 seconds if status != 0 then alert